# withFormik - how to show SetStatus message?

Tags: javascript, formik

Can anyone know how can i show Formik setStatus message in email field in form?

```
import { Form, Checkbox, Input, Button } from 'antd';
import { withFormik } from 'formik';
import axios from 'axios';

const RegistrationForm = (props) => {
  const { values, touched, errors, handleChange,
     handleBlur,handleSubmit, setFieldValue, status,
  } = props;

    console.log(status); //undefined

  return (
          <Form onFinish={handleSubmit}>
<Form.Item
  help={touched.email && errors.email ? errors.email : ""}
  validateStatus={touched.email && errors.email ? "error" : "success"}
  label="E-mail"
  name="email"
>
  <Input
    placeholder="Email"
    value={values.email}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
  />
</Form.Item>
<Form.Item>
    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
</Form.Item>
</Form>
  
const RegFormView = withFormik({
  validationSchema,
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ email: ''}),

  handleSubmit: async (values, { props, setErrors, setSubmitting, setStatus }) => {
    await axios.post("/signup", values)
        .then((response) => {
          setStatus('');
          const { isAdded } = response.data;
          const statusMessage = (isAdded) ? {message: 'User Added!'} : {message: 'User Not Added!'};
          setStatus(statusMessage);
          setSubmitting(false);
          console.log('response: ', response.data);
        }, (error) => { setErrors(error);
        });
    },
})(RegistrationForm);
export default RegFormView;
```

I removed all other fields from form.
server response: {isAdded: false} / {isAdded: true}
depends on have user with this email or not

Answer (score 2):

withFormik inject props into your component.

These props are the attributes of the Formik state and the functions that allows you to update it (like handleChange, setFieldValue, etc...).

So you can get the attribute status in the props of the component wrapped by withFormik.

```
const RegForm = (props) => {
  const { values, touched, status } = props;

  return <YourForm>
    <YourInput />
  </ YourForm>
}

export default withFormik({
  validationSchema,
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ name: '', password: '', email: '',}),

  handleSubmit: async (values, { props, setErrors, setSubmitting, setStatus }) => {
    await axios.post("/signup", values)
        .then((response) => {
          const { isAdded } = response.data;
          const message = (isAdded) ? 'yes' : 'no';
          setStatus(message);
          setSubmitting(false);
        }, (error) => {
          setErrors(error);
        });
    },
})(RegForm);
```

Comment: tryed this but its always 'undefined' :( may be i should use 'initialStatus' or 'mapPropsToStatus' but have no idea how. can't find any examples..

Comment: can you edit your post and show the full code snippets?

Comment: thank you for help, I added more code (and I remove other fields). I think I need setStatus() somewhere before handleSubmit :/